# The glue between DbContext, Repositories, and Services, am I getting it?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern

**Background:**
This is my first project using repositories, services, and entity framework. Right now I'm focused on the data layer, and how I should structure it. I'm just using SQLite, but I'll need Dropbox and the ability to read/write JSON objects to local storage, so I'm hoping by creating a data layer I can just add those features later.

**What I have:**

IRepository.cs

```
using System;

namespace Premier.Data.Repositories
{
    public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        void Create(TEntity entity);
        void Remove(TEntity entity);
        void Update(TEntity entity);
    }
}
```

Repository.cs

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;

namespace Premier.Data.Repositories
{
    public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        protected DbContext context;
        protected IDbSet<TEntity> entities;

        public Repository(DbContext dbContext)
        {
            context = dbContext;
            entities = dbContext.Set<TEntity>();
        }

        public void Create(TEntity entity)
        {
            entities.Add(entity);
        }

        public void Update(TEntity entity)
        {
            entities.Attach(entity);
            context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        protected IQueryable<TEntity> Query()
        {
            return entities;
        }

        public void Remove(TEntity entity)
        {
            entities.Remove(entity);
        }
    }
```

**What I don't understand:**

From what I read, a Service talks to a Repository, and my WPF project will just communicate with services. **Is that correct, or would the view models also access a repository?**

**Where ever I access these repositories, how do I ensure the DbContext has the latest data?** For example, in a departments view, a department can be added or deleted. Every interval on a continuous service running in this project needs the latest details as soon as it is available (or within a interval time). Originally I was going to use a hybrid between a factory and singleton to create repositories and let them share a DbContext. However, I read a SO question that said global DbContext is a bad idea. So now I'm left wondering, how I would answer the question of how to get recent info from my continuous service.

Thanks for your time, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer#1 
Yes you are correct, Services talks to repositories and WPF application will communicate only with services. One should not use repositories directly in ViewModels, it is not advisable.

Answer#2 
When you access these repositories, either you can create a new instance of DbContext to fetch latest data or you use the existing instance of DbContext (the instance you created before updating database). If you use a new instance then you will get the latest data. But if you use the existing DbContext then it will fetch old data.

Answer (score 1):

1) I'm not too experienced in WPF, but as I remember it is possible to bind some controls right to the database (Data Binding). In this case You don't even need Your repository pattern.

2) Anyway, Your Generic Repository is implemented quite well. IMHO, I prefer to to define only `DbContext` protected field. I think `IDbSet<TEntity>` field is redundant cause You can access it through the context (as You do in the constructor). So, instead of using

```
entities.Add(entity);
```

You can use this:

```
dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
```

Also, if You want to share one context between all repositories there is a good pattern called ***Unit Of Work***. Just google: ***Generic Repository + Unit Of Work + EF***. Put simply, it is a wrapper class around all repositories that You use. You just pass Your context object to the Unit Of Work constructor and it is shared between repositories. So, when You call `Save Changes` everything that You have chaged using any of Your repo is saved simultaneously.

And I think You need to define Your own context (that inherits from DbContext) and probably interface for it, so You can introduce Dependency Injection.

Hope this helps!

**Edits:** look at this question and answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295977/repository-service-design-pattern/19296295#19296295